# Regex on Postfix using Centos

Tags: centos, regular-expression, postfix

I have a Centos server running only postfix. I want to filter out mails containing word `gratis` or `grátis` or `grétis` or `grâtis`.

The second letter is the problem. So I used this rejex:

```
/^Subject:.*gr.tis/ REJECT Your message was rejected
```

The problem is that the "dot" does not match special characters with postfix. I mean, if I send an email with the word `gratis` on the subject it gets filtered. But if I send an email containing `grátis` it does not.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the spam sample to a file and examine it with, e.g., `cat -A`, `sed -n l`, `hexdump`, `hd`, `od` etc - whatever it takes to see what actual bytes are in the Subject: header.

e.g.

`grep '^Subject:' /tmp/saved.spam | sed -n l`

That will help you create an accurate regexp to put in your header_checks file.

Comment: do you have any idea how to filter a message and save its content to a file? I mean, when I reject a message can I also save it to a file?

Comment: AFAIK, no. it's not possible.  with header checks the msg is rejected during the SMTP session and never makes it into the postfix delivery queue.  You can do it if you use, e.g. spamassassin, instead of header_checks but then you lose the ability to reject during smtp (so you have to either deliver, discard, or quarantine any detected spam - do not bounce, otherwise you will be a backscatter spammer)

Comment: thanks @cas! So do you know any way to send the message to a log? I dont need to reject it, just analyze it. I use mailq but it only shows the content of the messages ID that are currently on queue.

Comment: if the message is in the queue, you can view it with `postcat`.  see `man postcat` for details.  Or you might like to try my `qvmenu.pl` script http://taz.net.au/postfix/scripts/qvmenu.pl if you don't mind installing a few perl modules.  i wrote it when i ran a mail server for an ISP and needed an easy way to examine spam stuck in the (quite large) queue to help me create better spam filters.

Comment: if it has been delivered, extract it from the mailbox it was delivered to.  otherwise, you're out of luck - if the message wasn't accepted, the contents would have been discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
/^Subject:.*gr.{1,2}tis/ REJECT Your message was rejected
```

instead. Perhaps it's a bug in encoding.

Comment: it's an ecoding problem with postfix but your solution didnt work. What really work was gr.{6,6}tis . Any idea why?

Comment: Maybe because when you type `grátis` it becomes `grM-CM-!tis`?

Comment: it's two byte utf8 on my system: `echo grátis | sed -n l` `gr\303\241tis$`....but it could be encoded differently in the incoming spam.

Comment: I checked the source code of the messag and special characters were being transformed in things like this "=?abu?" wtf?